# BUG IN DEVC++ (Comparing String and Character)

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm trying to make a program that will count how many letters occur in my string. I want only to count letters A and B on a give string.

```
char string[10];
int countA, countB;
gets(string);

for(int i = 0; i <strlen(string); i++){
    if(string[i] == 'A')
    countA++;
    else if(string[i] == 'B')
    countB++;
}

printf("%d %d", countA, countB);
return 0;
```

for example my  input is: ABABA
the output should be 3 2 however it print a different answer for countB. I'm using devc++. Is this  a bug?

Comment: What is suppose to Print ? please give a better explanation

Comment: Initialize countA and countB to zero. And enable all compiler warnings. And do not assume compiler bugs in the future, there are almost none (at least with common compilers)

Comment: Are `countA` and `countB` local or global? They're uninitialized so what you're seeing is undefined behaviour.

Comment: countA ang countB are both local. The problem is now fixed. I just need to initialize it values to 0. Thanks for all of your replies. :)

Comment: Avoid gets man -a gets for more info

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda *Is this a bug?* -- First, devC++ is not a compiler.  It is an integrated development environment (IDE).  The actual compiler is an older version of g++.  Second, even though the compiler is an old version of g++, that version was used by thousands of programmers and corporations around the world.  If  the compiler cannot properly compile that simple bit of code you have correctly, then g++ would be out of business or laughed at.  So is it a bug?  It is a bug in your program, not the compiler.

Comment: You assume that `countA` and `countB` start at zero; **but they do not**.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason for getting different result:

Earlier when you didn't initialize the variable `countA` and `countB` they contained indeterminate value. Using them in your code introduces undefined behavior.

Two points:

- Intialize the variables to zero. `countA` and `countB`.
- And don't use `gets` rather use `fgets`.

---

I am giving you an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(){
    char string[10];
    unsigned int countA=0, countB=0;
    if( fgets(string,10,stdin) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in string input");
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    if( len > 0 )
        string[len-1]='\0';
    for(size_t i = 0; i <strlen(string); i++){
        if(string[i] == 'A'){
            countA++;
        }
        else if(string[i] == 'B'){
            countB++;
        }

    }

    printf("%u %u", countA, countB);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Note:

1. Also you are asked whether it is gloabal variable. If it was then probably you wouldn't have to worry about initialization. They would be initialized with `0`.
2. `gets()` goes on reading characters until it encounters `\n` or `EOF`. And on doing this it is not constrained in anyway with the buffer size, leaving a chance of buffer overflow.

Comment: thank you for your response, the problem is ok now. haha. i just need to initialize it to 0. Thank You!